# Convert JQuery.Extend Accordion Menu to Dropdown Menu instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am updating our Accordion menu (navigation) and trying to remove the "SlideUp" feature. Instead of opening like an "accordion" i'd rather our menu drop down and overlay the rest of the page contents.

[image]

Here is my JS... right now its using jquery.extend but I know it should be a matter of switching properties and changing some of the logic to see this functionality work.

Here is my js:

```
    // open-close plugin
    jQuery.fn.OpenClose = function(_options){
// default options
var _options = jQuery.extend({
    activeClass:'active',
    opener:'.open-close',
    slider:'.slide',
    slideSpeed: 400,
    animStart:false,
    animEnd:false,
    event:'click'
 },_options);

 return this.each(function(){
    // options
    var _holder = jQuery(this);
    var _slideSpeed = _options.slideSpeed;
    var _activeClass = _options.activeClass;
    var _opener = jQuery(_options.opener, _holder);
    var _slider = jQuery(_options.slider, _holder);
    var _animStart = _options.animStart;
    var _animEnd = _options.animEnd;
    var _event = _options.event;
    if(_slider.length) {
        _opener.bind(_event,function(){
            if(!_slider.is(':animated')) {
                if(typeof _animStart === 'function') _animStart();
                if(_holder.hasClass(_activeClass)) {
                    _slider.slideUp(_slideSpeed,function(){
                        if(typeof _animEnd === 'function') _animEnd();
                    });
                    _holder.removeClass(_activeClass);
                } else {
                    _holder.addClass(_activeClass);
                    _slider.slideDown(_slideSpeed,function(){
                        if(typeof _animEnd === 'function') _animEnd();
                    });
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
        if(_holder.hasClass(_activeClass)) _slider.show();
        else _slider.hide();
        }
       });
         }
```

Comment: add `position:absolute`?

Comment: to what? the javascript? i did try this but it didn't work.

Comment: No...you don't add it to the javascript, you add it to your header menu.

Comment: no... it didnt work! the problem is not the css...the problem is the jquery i posted above. I need to change the options to offer a drop down solution rather a slideUp or slideDown.

Comment: Listen, I understand it's difficult to wrap your head around things initially, so I've [created this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSSq5/) to illustrate to you why adding `position:absolute` is the answer to your question. If you can't see that this will resolve your issue, then I'll just stop.

Comment: Position="Relative" did the trick. Thank you for stopping, no need to get upset. Sheeshh...

Comment: No one was upset, I was simply trying to get you to see that the jQuery method you were using had nothing to do with the CSS layout that you were attempting to achieve. Regardless, I'm glad to hear that you've got it working. Cheers.